# Why object shared between component get updated but not primitive type like string

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have one shared Service and Two sibling components.
When I have object shared between these two components and I try to change property of one of the object It gets updated but when I have String type shared data It is not updated.If this is the working Why Do I need RXJS then

I know It is object so by reference It should get updated but It is not written anywhere on Angular documentation

Here is my code for service and components

**SERVICE**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

    @Injectable()
    export class AppServiceService {

      data = [{ name: 'init' }];
      sharedData: Data[];

      // sharedData = new BehaviorSubject<Data[]>(this.data);
      constructor() {

        this.sharedData = this.data;

      }

      getData() {
        return this.sharedData;
      }

    }


    export interface Data {

      name: string;
      city?: string;

    }
```

**COMPONENT 1**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppServiceService, Data } from '../app-service.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-hero',
      templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
    })
    export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {

      data: Data[];

      constructor(private appService: AppServiceService) { }

      ngOnInit() {

        this.data = this.appService.getData();

      }

      changeValue() {
        this.data[0].name = 'kashif';
        this.data[0].city = 'mumbra';
      }

    }
```

**COMPONENT 2**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppServiceService, Data } from '../app-service.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-villain',
      templateUrl: './villain.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./villain.component.css']
    })
    export class VillainComponent implements OnInit {

      data: Data[];

      constructor(private appService: AppServiceService) { }

      ngOnInit() {

        this.data = this.appService.getData();

      }

    }
```

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, please leave a comment.

Comment: NO, I am asking this is not angular behaviour It should return copy object in this case.

Comment: I don't think It is duplicate question.

Comment: But that is the expected behavior. For objects a reference is passed, for primitive values a copy is passed. If you change it on one side, you need to pass the value again. You can wrap a primitive value in an object and pass the object, then when you change the value in the object, the receiver will see the updated value.

Comment: It also gets updated on UI how angular knows the change detection If I am manipulating object.